# How to flatten IO [[String]]?

Tags: haskell, io

I am new to Haskell and have some difficulties wrapping my head around some of it's concepts.

While playing around with IO I wanted to flatten an IO [[String]].

An example of what I have tried:

```
module DatabaseTestSO where

import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.MySQL
import Data.Foldable

convSqlValue :: [SqlValue] -> [String]
convSqlValue xs = [ getString x | x <- xs ]
    where getString value = case fromSql value of
                Just x -> x
                Nothing -> "Null"

listValues :: [[SqlValue]] -> [[String]]
listValues [] = []
listValues xs = [ convSqlValue x | x <- xs ]

flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten = Data.Foldable.foldl (++) []

domains :: IO [[String]]
domains =
    do  conn <- connectMySQL defaultMySQLConnectInfo {
                mysqlHost       = "hostname",
                mysqlDatabase   = "dbname",
                mysqlUser       = "username",
                mysqlPassword   = "pass" }

        queryDomains <- quickQuery conn "SELECT name FROM domains" []

        return (listValues queryDomains)
```

That works with `[[String]]` in GHCi as expected:

```
*DatabaseTestSO> flatten [["blah","blab","wah"],["bloh","blob","woh"],["blih","blib","wuh"]]
["blah","blab","wah","bloh","blob","woh","blih","blib","wuh"]
```

but does not with `IO [[String]]` where I get

```
*DatabaseTestSO> flatten domains 

<interactive>:1:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[a0]]'
                with actual type `IO [[String]]'
    In the first argument of `flatten', namely `domains'
    In the expression: flatten domains
    In an equation for `it': it = flatten domains
```

I guess I can not use a function that is supposed to be pure with IO types?
Can I convert `IO [[String]]` to `[[String]]`?
How do I solve this problem correctly?

Comment: `flatten` is called `concat` and is defined in `Prelude`.

Comment: I see. Is `Prelude` imported automatically when not using GHCi?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to realize what `IO something` means. It's not a `something`, it's an **action that will return a `something`** (In this case, `something` is `[[String]]`). So, you cannot do anything with the thing that the action returns, until you perform the action, which returns that thing.

You have two options to solve your problem.

1. Perform the action, and use the result. This is done like this:

   ```
   do
     ds <- domains       -- Perform action, and save result in ds
     return $ flatten ds -- Flatten the result ds
   ```
2. Create a new action that takes the result of some action, and applies a function to it. The new action then returns the transformed value. This is done with the `liftM` function in the `Control.Monad` module.

   ```
   import Control.Monad
   -- ...

   do
     -- Creates a new action that flattens the result of domains
     let getFlattenedDomains = liftM flatten domains

     -- Perform the new action to get ds, which contains the flattened result
     ds <- getFlattenedDomains

     return ds
   ```

PS. You might want to rename your `domains` variable to `getDomains` to clarify what it does. It's not a pure value; it's a monadic action that returns a pure value.

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: Note: `fmap` = `liftM` = `liftA` = `<$>`.

Answer (score 10):

You can't get anything "out" of IO, so what you need to do is lift `flatten` to work inside it. The simplest way to do this is `fmap`--just like `map` applies a function over a list, `fmap` applies a function over any `Functor` instance, such as `IO`.

```
flattenIO xs = fmap flatten xs
```

In more general cases, you can use `do` notation to get at things in `IO` computations. For example:

```
flattenIO xs = do ys <- xs
                  return (flatten ys)
```

...which is just a roundabout way of writing `fmap` in this case.