# return IO(Data.Vector.Storable.Vector) from Haskell to C

Tags: c, haskell, vector, monads

I am trying to pass `IO (Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double)` from Haskell to C, but there seem to be a problem as Haskell does not allow that. In this case, should I pass a pointer to the vector back to the C program (then how to wrap this object in Ptr) or is there another way?

Also, `Data.Vector.Storable` seem to have `toList` function, but when I try to use it, the program does not compile complaining that the Vector is wrapped in IO Monad.

I have tried to find a way to unwrap Vector from IO Monad, but failed to find anything specific, seems like to do so, the IO wrapped object has to be passed to another function, which would have to return back the IO wrapped object again, which, in my opinion, would lead to the same problem again as IO wrapped objects cannot be passed back to C program from the interface.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Safe where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Data.Vector.Storable
import AI.HNN.Recurrent.Network

foreign export ccall process :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr Double -> IO (Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double) -> IO ()

feed :: [Double] -> IO (Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double)
feed adj = do
    let numNeurons = 3
        numInputs  = 1
        thresholds = Prelude.replicate numNeurons 0.5
        inputs     = [[0.38], [0.75]]
    n <- createNetwork numNeurons numInputs adj thresholds :: IO (Network Double)
    output <- evalNet n inputs sigmoid
    return output

peekInt :: Ptr CInt -> IO Int
peekInt = fmap fromIntegral . peek

process :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr Double -> IO (Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double) -> IO ()
process n xs result = do
    n <- peekInt n
    es <- peekArray n xs
    poke result $ (feed es)
```

Calling and collecting from C

```
double res = [output_size];
int asize = sizeof(weights)/sizeof(double);
process(&asize, &weights, &res);
```

Comment: Try using `unsafeToForeignPtr` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.1.5/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Devel.html

Comment: Or the `vector` package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.3/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html

Comment: @vivian Tried `(fptr, len) <- unsafeToForeignPtr0 (feed es)` , but again, I am getting `Couldn't match expected type ‘Vector a0’ with actual type ‘IO (Vector Double)’` Due to IO wrapping

Comment: P.S. This is the first time I am dealing with Monads, so I may be doing it all wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it partly "all wrong". You should start with a tutorial on IO that explains that values of type `IO a` are not "IO wrapped [values of type `a`]" but rather IO actions that would produce a value of type `a` if executed. And, it looks like you want the third argument of `process` to just have type `Ptr Double`.

Comment: @ReidBarton The third argument is an `out` variable that is expected to be used to communicate the vector in one form or another back to the C program

Comment: Yes, I see that. But in C a pointer can be used for that also. You should first write down the C type you want your function to have. From your example usage it looks like `void process(int *, double *, double *)` (not sure why the first argument needs to be a pointer, but OK). Then just directly transcribe that into a Haskell type.

Comment: @ReidBarton I do not know how to do that, but I will try to find out

Comment: @ReidBarton I may be wring, but is it this you are telling me about? https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/ghc/users_guide/ffi.html#ffi-newtype-io

Comment: See also: "[Can I turn `IO [[String]]` into `[[String]]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8626392/791604)".

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you, that was the most valuable comment

Comment: To summarise, to flatten/unwrap `IO (anything?)`, the action must be performed: `result <- (feed ..)`